# Do a python program lcd 20x4 display need to used RPi GPIO 08 pin?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, lcd

I have created a python program used `wxpython` module to display output from mcp3008 which convert data from analog to digital from rain sensor. This project I'm doing is to upgrade the current project with only display data through lcd 20x4 display from other input or source. But the my `wxpython` program used the `GPIO08` pin which has a `SPIO_CE0_N` function for spi bus as my `mcp3008` required it to check my other spi pin. This my mcp3008 pin layout to raspberry pi:

```
VDD   3.3V
VREF  3.3V
AGND  GROUND
CLK   GPIO11 (P1-23)
DOUT  GPIO9  (P1-21)
DIN   GPIO10 (P1-19)
CS    GPIO8  (P1-24)
DGND  GROUND
```

And this is lcd 20x4 display pin layout to raspberry pi:

```
LCD Pin Function    Pi Function Pi Pin
01  GND GND P1-06
02  +5V +5V P1-02
03  Contrast        
04  RS  GPIO7   P1-26
05  RW  GND P1-06
06  E   GPIO8   P1-24
07  Data 0      
08  Data 1      
09  Data 2      
10  Data 3      
11  Data 4  GPIO25  P1-22
12  Data 5  GPIO24  P1-18
13  Data 6  GPIO23  P1-16
14  Data 7  GPIO18  P1-12
15  +5V via 560 ohm     
16  GND     P1-06
```

As the python program for the lcd display i get from the internet use `GPIO 08` in the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#--------------------------------------
#    ___  ___  _ ____
#   / _ \/ _ \(_) __/__  __ __
#  / , _/ ___/ /\ \/ _ \/ // /
# /_/|_/_/  /_/___/ .__/\_, /
#                /_/   /___/
#
#  lcd_16x2.py
#  20x4 LCD Test Script with
#  backlight control and text justification
#
# Author : Matt Hawkins
# Date   : 06/04/2015
#
# http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/
#
#--------------------------------------

# The wiring for the LCD is as follows:
# 1 : GND
# 2 : 5V
# 3 : Contrast (0-5V)*
# 4 : RS (Register Select)
# 5 : R/W (Read Write)       - GROUND THIS PIN
# 6 : Enable or Strobe
# 7 : Data Bit 0             - NOT USED
# 8 : Data Bit 1             - NOT USED
# 9 : Data Bit 2             - NOT USED
# 10: Data Bit 3             - NOT USED
# 11: Data Bit 4
# 12: Data Bit 5
# 13: Data Bit 6
# 14: Data Bit 7
# 15: LCD Backlight +5V**
# 16: LCD Backlight GND

#import
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Define GPIO to LCD mapping
LCD_RS = 7
LCD_E  = 8
LCD_D4 = 25
LCD_D5 = 24
LCD_D6 = 23
LCD_D7 = 18
LED_ON = 15

# Define some device constants
LCD_WIDTH = 20    # Maximum characters per line
LCD_CHR = True
LCD_CMD = False

LCD_LINE_1 = 0x80 # LCD RAM address for the 1st line
LCD_LINE_2 = 0xC0 # LCD RAM address for the 2nd line
LCD_LINE_3 = 0x94 # LCD RAM address for the 3rd line
LCD_LINE_4 = 0xD4 # LCD RAM address for the 4th line

# Timing constants
E_PULSE = 0.0005
E_DELAY = 0.0005

def main():
  # Main program block

  GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)       # Use BCM GPIO numbers
  GPIO.setup(LCD_E, GPIO.OUT)  # E
  GPIO.setup(LCD_RS, GPIO.OUT) # RS
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D4, GPIO.OUT) # DB4
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D5, GPIO.OUT) # DB5
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D6, GPIO.OUT) # DB6
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D7, GPIO.OUT) # DB7
  GPIO.setup(LED_ON, GPIO.OUT) # Backlight enable

  # Initialise display
  lcd_init()

  # Toggle backlight on-off-on
  lcd_backlight(True)
  time.sleep(0.5)
  lcd_backlight(False)
  time.sleep(0.5)
  lcd_backlight(True)
  time.sleep(0.5)

  while True:

    # Send some centred test
    lcd_string("--------------------",LCD_LINE_1,2)
    lcd_string("Rasbperry Pi",LCD_LINE_2,2)
    lcd_string("Model B",LCD_LINE_3,2)
    lcd_string("--------------------",LCD_LINE_4,2)

    time.sleep(3) # 3 second delay

    lcd_string("Raspberrypi-spy",LCD_LINE_1,3)
    lcd_string(".co.uk",LCD_LINE_2,3)
    lcd_string("",LCD_LINE_3,2)
    lcd_string("20x4 LCD Module Test",LCD_LINE_4,2)

    time.sleep(3) # 20 second delay

    # Blank display
    lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)

    time.sleep(3) # 3 second delay

def lcd_init():
  # Initialise display
  lcd_byte(0x33,LCD_CMD) # 110011 Initialise
  lcd_byte(0x32,LCD_CMD) # 110010 Initialise
  lcd_byte(0x06,LCD_CMD) # 000110 Cursor move direction
  lcd_byte(0x0C,LCD_CMD) # 001100 Display On,Cursor Off, Blink Off
  lcd_byte(0x28,LCD_CMD) # 101000 Data length, number of lines, font size
  lcd_byte(0x01,LCD_CMD) # 000001 Clear display
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)

def lcd_byte(bits, mode):
  # Send byte to data pins
  # bits = data
  # mode = True  for character
  #        False for command

  GPIO.output(LCD_RS, mode) # RS

  # High bits
  GPIO.output(LCD_D4, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D5, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D6, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D7, False)
  if bits&0x10==0x10:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D4, True)
  if bits&0x20==0x20:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D5, True)
  if bits&0x40==0x40:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D6, True)
  if bits&0x80==0x80:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D7, True)

  # Toggle 'Enable' pin
  lcd_toggle_enable()

  # Low bits
  GPIO.output(LCD_D4, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D5, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D6, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D7, False)
  if bits&0x01==0x01:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D4, True)
  if bits&0x02==0x02:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D5, True)
  if bits&0x04==0x04:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D6, True)
  if bits&0x08==0x08:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D7, True)

  # Toggle 'Enable' pin
  lcd_toggle_enable()

def lcd_toggle_enable():
  # Toggle enable
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)
  GPIO.output(LCD_E, True)
  time.sleep(E_PULSE)
  GPIO.output(LCD_E, False)
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)

def lcd_string(message,line,style):
  # Send string to display
  # style=1 Left justified
  # style=2 Centred
  # style=3 Right justified

  if style==1:
    message = message.ljust(LCD_WIDTH," ")
  elif style==2:
    message = message.center(LCD_WIDTH," ")
  elif style==3:
    message = message.rjust(LCD_WIDTH," ")

  lcd_byte(line, LCD_CMD)

  for i in range(LCD_WIDTH):
    lcd_byte(ord(message[i]),LCD_CHR)

def lcd_backlight(flag):
  # Toggle backlight on-off-on
  GPIO.output(LED_ON, flag)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  try:
    main()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
  finally:
    lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_string("Goodbye!",LCD_LINE_1,2)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

So my question is can i change the pin for lcd display that used `GPIO 08` to other pin and change the program to used the changing RPi pin as i don't know whether the lcd display python program need to used the `SPIO_CE0_N` in `GPIO 08` or only used the `GPIO 08` without the `SPIO_CE0_N` function.

Answer (score 0):

You use `GPIO 8` for `SPI_CE0` on Raspberry Pi only if you are using *hardware SPI*, and from your `MCP3008` connections, it is pretty clear that you are.

The simplest solution is to use `Software SPI` for `MCP3008` instead, and connect MCP3008 `CLK`, `DOUT`, `DIN`, and `CS/SHDN` pins to any other free digital GPIO pins, and use your `GPIO08` for your LCD connections. Or you can do the opposite and use software SPI for your LCD.

Switching from hardware SPI to software SPI is easy, you only have to change pin numbers in the code. You can read more details on using Software SPI with `MCP3008` here, https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters/mcp3008#software-spi

GPIO image for future reference,

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer. But do i need to download and install the Adafruit_Python_MCP3008 library as it is done in the web you give?

Comment: And also i get ImportError: no module named Adafruit_MCP3008 after I follow the step to install the library from the web and run my rain sensor program on the desktop.But when I try to run the example program it can read the Adafruit_MCP3008 module. The CS pin I change it to used pin 29 or GPIO 5 in my rain sensor program as pin 24 or GPIO 8 is used by the LCD.

Comment: Please look at the sample example code `simpletest.py` in example folder, given here https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MCP3008